# clang-format malforming comment blocks

Tags: clang-format

Quick question:

I have some [code](https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libiio/blob/master/iiod/iiod.c#L656-L665) that looks like:

```
if (interactive)
    ret = main_interactive(ctx, debug, use_aio);
else
    ret = main_server(ctx, debug);

/*
 * In case we got here through an error in the main thread make sure all
 * the worker threads are signaled to shutdown.
 */
```

when I run it through clang-format 7.0.1-8 (debian) (with this [.clang-format](https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libiio/blob/rgetz-coding-style/.clang-format) file), I get [this](https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libiio/blob/rgetz-coding-style/iiod/iiod.c#L652-661):

```
if (interactive)
    ret = main_interactive(ctx, debug, use_aio);
else
    ret = main_server(ctx, debug);

    /*
 * In case we got here through an error in the main thread make sure all
 * the worker threads are signaled to shutdown.
 */
```

You can see that the first line of the comment block is incorrectly indented.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your error. If you use a different system and config file, it is unlikely that you will see this problem.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it on a different system with the same config file. I did not use just the snippet, but the entire file, in case something about the top of the file is confusing clang-format.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried you clang-format config in CLion 2020.RC1 and it seems the problem is comment's first line (`/*`) is indented with tab (which is 8-spaces wide per your config), while the rest of the comment's lines are indented with 4 spaces.
Here is how you code looks like with "show whitespace: on" in CLion:

[image: code with whitespace]

This can be fixed with option `ReflowComments: true`. That way all comment's lines will be indented with tabs.

Comment: Thanks - this does indent things (lines up the comments), but it lines them up with the indented `ret = main ...` rather than one back (where the flow should be. There is no {} around the else, the comment is a header for the next block of code, and doesn't have anything to do with the previous if/else....